# Дать возможность группировать избранное

Tags: предложение, избранное

Иногда мы натакливаемся на интересные вопросы и добавляем их в избранное, например, для того, что бы при необходимости когда-нибудь вернутся к нему.

Допустим, там доступным языком может быть описан какой-нибудь шаблон и через некоторое время нам потребуется освежить память.

Так вот, сейчас при добавлении в избранное все сваливается в кучу.

Почему бы не дать возможность создавать свои личные группы и производить группировку между ними?

Например, вот этот перечень избранного я помещу в работу с потоками, а вот эту в паттерны.

Собственно, это позволит быстро искать вопрос в избранном, что повысит юзабилити.

А сейчас избранное может превратится в свалку в которой ничего нельзя быстро найти если в избранном находится слишком много всего.

Comment: Я - за. Тоже не хватает такой фичи.

Comment: Теги (метки) же есть, вы описали роль которую они должны исполнять

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да, но сделать я с ними ничего не могу. Например, выбрав кнокретную метку в избранном открываются все вопросы этой метки... => Что бы найти что-то нужно, что косвенно я помню, что добавлял в избранное, я должен глазами пробежаться по всему.

Comment: Вот это уже другой вопрос, но, скорее всего, должны быть ключи для поиска только по избранному. Ну и, возможно, было бы удобным добавление личных приватных меток, которые никто не увидит кроме поставившего. Но это довольно большая фича и я сомневаюсь, что ее внедрят.

Comment: С другой стороны, есть сторонние каталогизаторы, которые, скорее всего, больше подойдут под вашу задачу, т. к. они могут хранить ссылки не только на страницы на SO, но и на любые другие страницы в интернете + имеют кучу других фич

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну сейчас тогда от избранного толку 0, так как если активно туда добавлять то, что может пригодится в будущем, то оно становится нечитаемым=(

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ну тогда проще руками в хроме создавать собственноручно закладки, но имхо- это не совсем правильно. Так как если бы на сайте было бы более функциональное избранное, то можно было бы видеть какую-то доп. актуальную информацию, например рейтинг и все такоею

Comment: Не сравнивайте закладки и полноценные каталогизаторы, с тегами, полнотекстовым поиском и прочим :)

Answer (score 5):

Тредов много на эту тему:

- [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944/260198).
- [Better favourites organisation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3912/260198).

Вроде не планируется пока изменений, задача совсем не в приоритете. Пока можно костыльно по списку избранного делать поиск, по крайней мере:

1. Мои избранные посты по метке: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3Amine+[faq]
2. Моё избранное по топик стартеру: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A15479+%5Bfaq%5D+user%3A6
3. С поиском по строке: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A15479+%5Bfaq%5D+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8

Или написать расширение для браузера. Хотя, на https://stackapps.com/ что-то уже есть вроде.

Типо такого можно за основу взять: [Favourites Enhancer: Tag favourites and add personal notes](https://stackapps.com/q/6215/55022).